# Pandas to_datetime function giving erratic output

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

My data frame has a column 'Date' which is of type object but I want to convert it to pandas time series. So I am using pd.to_datetime function. This function is converting the datatype but giving erratic output.

code:

```
x1['TS'] = pd.to_datetime(x1['Date'])       
x1['Day'] = x1['TS'].dt.dayofweek      
x1[['Date', 'TS', 'Day']].iloc[::1430,:]
```

Now notice the output closely and see the columns Date and TS. it should be same but in some cases, its different.

output :

```
        Date            TS     Day
0       01-12-2017  2017-01-12  3
1430    01-12-2017  2017-01-12  3
2860    02-12-2017  2017-02-12  6
4290    03-12-2017  2017-03-12  6
5720    04-12-2017  2017-04-12  2
7150    05-12-2017  2017-05-12  4
8580    07-12-2017  2017-07-12  2
10010   08-12-2017  2017-08-12  5
11440   09-12-2017  2017-09-12  1
12870   09-12-2017  2017-09-12  1
14300   10-12-2017  2017-10-12  3
15730   11-12-2017  2017-11-12  6
17160   12-12-2017  2017-12-12  1
18590   13-12-2017  2017-12-13  2
20020   14-12-2017  2017-12-14  3
21450   15-12-2017  2017-12-15  4
22880   16-12-2017  2017-12-16  5
24310   17-12-2017  2017-12-17  6
25740   18-12-2017  2017-12-18  0
27170   19-12-2017  2017-12-19  1
28600   20-12-2017  2017-12-20  2
30030   21-12-2017  2017-12-21  3
31460   22-12-2017  2017-12-22  4
32890   23-12-2017  2017-12-23  5
34320   24-12-2017  2017-12-24  6
35750   25-12-2017  2017-12-25  0
37180   26-12-2017  2017-12-26  1
38610   27-12-2017  2017-12-27  2
40040   28-12-2017  2017-12-28  3
41470   29-12-2017  2017-12-29  4
42900   30-12-2017  2017-12-30  5
44330   31-12-2017  2017-12-31  6
45760   01-01-2018  2018-01-01  0
47190   02-01-2018  2018-02-01  3
48620   03-01-2018  2018-03-01  3
50050   04-01-2018  2018-04-01  6
51480   05-01-2018  2018-05-01  1
52910   06-01-2018  2018-06-01  4
54340   07-01-2018  2018-07-01  6
55770   08-01-2018  2018-08-01  2
57200   09-01-2018  2018-09-01  5
58630   10-01-2018  2018-10-01  0
60060   11-01-2018  2018-11-01  3
61490   12-01-2018  2018-12-01  5
62920   13-01-2018  2018-01-13  5
64350   14-01-2018  2018-01-14  6
65780   15-01-2018  2018-01-15  0
67210   16-01-2018  2018-01-16  1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oops! Looks like your dates start with the day being first. You'll have to tell pandas to handle that accordingly. Set the `dayfirst` flag to `True` when calling `to_datetime`.

```
x1['TS'] = pd.to_datetime(x1['Date'], dayfirst=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

When you pass in a time without specifying the format, Pandas tries to guess at the format in a naive manner. It was assuming that what is your day is actually your month but then when it sees that it is month 13, realizes that can't be the month column and switches.

The following should work but I like @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's solution better because it is simpler to just raise the dayfirst flag.

To fix this, provide the current format to the to_datetime function.

The documentation gives the following example which you can modify to fit your situation:

```
pd.to_datetime('13000101', format='%Y%m%d', errors='ignore')
```

See details here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html

Time format conventions (what %Y means and so on) are here: https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/time.html